# Android showing test ads when it should be a real ad

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have implemented Native Ads in an Android application, I've used the correct Admob app ID and the Admob unit ID, the ads are showing but it shows test ads only.

**Note** The application has been alive for a few weeks now, however, it only has tester users for making some changes after mass publication.

Comment: Are you testing in emulator!?

Comment: please share code

Comment: @DaxeshV sadly I don't have the code anymore

Answer (score 0):

Extract the final application.
And leverage on the Google Store.
Second, there should be some people using the app to show real ads

**Edit 2023**

The ad is not displayed in development mode to prevent views and clicks from being counted. This is considered illegal visits. If the ad is displayed in development mode, your account may be banned.

Comment: the application is in Release mode, and the application is being used and downloaded from the PlayStore